# List custom post types with custom taxonomy category assigned to them

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called `products` and custom taxonomy called `product-category`.
Now I need to list all the posts from this product post type which have product-category assigned to them. I thought something like this could work, but no luck. Could anyone point me in the right direction, please?! Really appreciate your help!

[image]

```
<?php $category = get_search_query();

$args = array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'product_category',
    'post_type'     => 'products',
    'category_name' => $category
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// OR

$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'products',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product-category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $category
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>


<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <div class="products">
        <ul>
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>

                <li><?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' ); ?></li>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to add the `relation` to your args.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'products',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
            'terms'    => $category,
            'field'    => 'slug',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Also, check:

- Is the post type spelled correctly (i.e. Are you sure it's `products` and not `product`?)
- In your first query you have `product_category` but in your second query you have `product-category`. Should it be a hyphen or an underscore?
- Is the value returned by `$category` valid?

Comment: Shoelaced thank you so much for your help! I was messing around with the `relation` before as well but surely I was not getting the syntax quite right. You are also right about the `product_category`, I might have made a mistake replacing the underscore with a hyphen. Using your correct syntax and `product_category` with underscore works like a charm! Many thanks again!

Comment: Pleasure! Glad you got it.